# Configuration of modules in Jboss AS7 domain mode

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

While runnning JBoss EAP 6.2 in domain mode do we have to configure modules in all instances or is there some way to make the modules accessible throughout the domain

Answer (score 0):

modules are accessible to all the instances which are there `host.xml`. If you have custom module and instances are configured on remote machine i.e slave, then you have to copy your custom modules to that instillation too.